# How to get last string in TStringList

Tags: string, delphi, tstringlist

I've been searching for days on how to do this, and nothing is exactly what I need to do (or I just don't understand how to implement the solution).

What I need to do is parse a string, which is a street address, into a TStringList, and then set those strings from the list to variables I can then pass to the rest of the program. I already have the list working ok:

```
var
AddressList : TStringList;
i : integer;

begin
AddressList := TStringList.Create;
AddressList.Delimiter := ' ';
AddressList.DelimitedText := RawAddressStr; //RawAddressStr is parsed from another file and the string result is something like '1234 Dark Souls Lane Wyoming, MI 48419'

for i := 0 to AddressList.Count-1 do
   AddressList.Strings[i]; //Not sure what to do here
```

The issue is that the address isn't always the same length. The address will sometimes be like '1234 Dark Souls Two Lane Wyoming...' or '1234 Dark Lane Wyoming...'

So I need to be able to use this TStringList to set the Zip, State and City into variables for later use. I would use TStringList.Find, but the ZIP code isn't always the same. Is there a way to get the last string and then go backwards from there? (Going backwards because once I get the City, State ZIP I can remove that from the RawAddressStr and then set the rest to the address string.)

Thanks.

Edit, here's the code I needed (thanks to below comments):
    AddressList := TStringList.Create;

```
AddressList.Delimiter := ' ';
AddressList.DelimitedText := RawAddressStr;

for i := 0 to AddressList.Count-1 do
  LastIndex := AddressList.Count - 1;
  ZipStr := AddressList[LastIndex];
  StateStr := AddressList[LastIndex - 1];
  CityStr := AddressList[LastIndex - 2];
```

Now I can use these with StringReplace to take out the City, State Zip from the full address string, and set that as the Address string to use.

Comment: The last string has index Count-1

Comment: The last string in `AdressList` is `AdressList.Strings[AdressList.Count - 1]` (which can be abbreviated `AdressList[AdressList.Count - 1]`).

Comment: Thanks, I can now get the Zip code reliably. How do I count backwards from there? So I can set City, State and Zip?

Comment: `LastIndex := AddressList.Count - 1;`, and then decrement (subtract from) `LastIndex` by 1 until you reach `0`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed! I can now get the last three strings by the index and set them to variables, which is what I needed to do. Since I can get these three, I can take those out of the full address string and set that to AddressStr. Perfect!

Comment: That'll work fine until you get someone with a city name like "South San Francisco" or "San Antonio", or state like "New Jersey". Frankly, while I see what you're trying to do, I think you're whole approach is ill-advised, and will lead to nothing but frustration long-term. The USPS has a web service that allows you to submit an address and it will return you one in "normalized" form, with corrections to boot.

Comment: Hmm, you added a solution to your question, but there's a for-loop there that serves no purpose at all. Also take care about using `begin` and `end`, as it stands now, only LastIndex will get assigned AddresList.Count times... Indentation doesn't control code flow in Delphi/ObjectPascal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am a little bit unsure of exactly what you're looking for since you ask
of how to get the last string of your StringList,
then at the end of the question you ask

> Is there a way to get the last string and then go backwards from
>   there?

If you want to get the last string of a StringList you can use

```
  var AddressList : TStringList;
      MyString: string;
begin
  MyString := AddressList.Last; //this...
  MyString := AddressList.Strings[AddressList.Count-1]; //...and this is essentially the same thing
end;
```

if you would like to for-loop in reverse or backwards you should write:

```
for i := AddressList.Count-1 downto 0 do
  AddressList.Strings[i]; //Not sure what to do here
```

Notice that it says "DOWNTO" and not "TO".

Now, if you would like to stop at a specific string, lets say the ZIP code,
you need to make your software understand what it is reading.

Which one of the delimited strings is the City?
Which one is the address?
To the software, a string is a string, it doesn't know, or even care what it is reading.

So I would like to suggest that you have a database of citys which it can compare the strings
of AddressList t,o and see if there is a match.

You could also implement some logic in to your algorithm.
If you know that the last string of your delimited AdressList string always is the City-name,
then you know you have the city name right there which you can use.

If you know that everything between the ZIP code and the City Name is the Street Address,
then just copy everything between the ZIP and the City-name and use that as a Street-name information.

Comment: tStringList doesn't have LAST method. only tList does.